# How to use InvalidModelState with SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

When `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` is false
i get free syntax object validation but with generic response,
i want the logic inside and use my own custom response

today i use `IsModelValid` function to validate the model

but i want also validate the syntax

```
bool IsModelValid(dynamic model)
{
    var validator = new DataAnnotationsValidator.DataAnnotationsValidator();
    
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

    if (!validator.TryValidateObjectRecursive(model, validationResults))
    {

    }
}
```

how to add syntax validation logic that inside `ModelStateInvalidFilter`?

Comment: I think you should find a solution to relapce it with another filter

Answer (score 0):

```
  private async Task<string> SyntaxValidation(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        string errMsg = null;
        Type? type = context?.ActionDescriptor?.Parameters?.FirstOrDefault()?.ParameterType;
        if (type is null)
        {
            return errMsg;
        }

        string contentType = context?.HttpContext?.Request?.ContentType?.ToLower();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
        {
            return errMsg;
        }

        try
        {
            using MemoryStream memoryStream = new();

            if (contentType.Contains("application/json"))
            {
                await context.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                if (memoryStream.Length == 0)
                {
                    return errMsg;
                }
                var res = await memoryStream.DeserializeAsync(type);
            }
            else
            {
                return errMsg;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errMsg = ex.Message;
        }

        return errMsg;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**